# Maximum Size of console in C

Tags: c, console, size

I'm just starting with C, and I've a problem with the size of the console. How can I do, to execute mi program, with the maximum size of the console? Can I adjust that? I need your help!

Thanks!

Comment: What platform are you running the program on?

Comment: If you just have started with C, then what you're trying to do is too advanced.

Comment: What do you mean by size of the console? Width of the terminal? In pixels or characters? Height? Something else? Why do you need it?

Comment: I'm running in Windows. Using CodeBlocks. With  size i mean, when I compile and run my code, I want the console in his maximum size on the screen. Full screen, to see the results. (PD: Sorry for my basic english)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of the console is system dependent. The way to programmatically resize the terminal, depends on the system and is not always possible.